# ImageJ: Multiple rectangle selections on an image

Tags: macros, selection, imagej

I would like to create a macro which:

- lets the user make several rectangular selections on an image
- saves the coordinates of all rectangles in a text file.

I am able to do it like this but only with a dialog box, where the user has to click on OK to continue his selection. But I want it to be quick, so without the dialog box.

```
while (flags&rightButton==0){
    makeRectangle(424, 333, 194, 151);
    waitForUser("Adjust your rectangle");
    getBoundingRect(x, y, width, height);
    wait(1000);
    getCursorLoc(x, y, z, flags);
    print(x,y,width,height);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Bastien

Comment: Could you show the code used to achieve your current result?

Comment: Here is my current code. But really not efficient!

while (flags&rightButton==0){
makeRectangle(424, 333, 194, 151);
waitForUser("Adjust your rectangle");
getBoundingRect(x, y, width, height);
wait(1000);
getCursorLoc(x, y, z, flags);
print(x,y,width,height);
}

Comment: Mind putting it in formatted in an [edit] to the question?

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me that it will be hard to keep the number of clicks down when trying to solve this with a macro.

Alternatively there is the RoiManager. Then draw a ROI, and hit `T` key to add it to the list. Then you can save all the ROI's with More>Save. Or you use your macro to iterate over the ROI's and do something with them (save coordinates to a text file, or apply the ROI to another image)

Comment: Yes, this works but won't fit my needs of running that in a macro running on hundreds of images...

Comment: yes, I was affaid of that. Please follow the questions of @LW001, put your current code and describe the workflow in detail, and mention the exact steps you want to optimize.